# First-chance exception at 0x00BDED43 in hw04.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and have been trying out some coding. I tried to implement deletion operation on avl trees. My insertion operation on the trees works fine but I am running into an error for my delete operation. I would be grateful if someone could help me fix the error.

The error is as follows :

First-chance exception at 0x00BDED43 in hw04.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. I am getting the following error when the code hits at the bf function in my code where it is returning the difference of height of right subtree - height of left subtree.

Following is my code :

```
int AVLTree::height(IAVLTreeNode*curr)
{
if (curr == NULL)
{
return 0;
}
int left_height = height(curr->getLeft());
int right_height = height(curr->getRight());
if (left_height > right_height){
return left_height + 1;
}
else {
return right_height + 1;
}
}

int AVLTree::bf(IAVLTreeNode*p)
{
return (height(((AVLTreeNode*)p)->getRight()) - height((AVLTreeNode*)p->getLeft()));
}


IAVLTreeNode*AVLTree::balance(IAVLTreeNode*p)
{
if (bf(p) == 2)
{
if (bf(p->getRight() )< 0)
p->setRight(rotateright((AVLTreeNode*)p->getRight()));
return rotateleft(p);
}

if (bf(p)==-2)
{
if (bf(p->getLeft())>0)
p->setLeft(rotateleft((AVLTreeNode*)p->getLeft()));
return rotateright(p);
}
return p;  }


IAVLTreeNode* AVLTree::rotateright(IAVLTreeNode*p)
{
AVLTreeNode*q =(AVLTreeNode*) p->getLeft();
p->setLeft(q->getRight());
q->setRight(p);
return q;
}


IAVLTreeNode* AVLTree::rotateleft(IAVLTreeNode*q)
{

AVLTreeNode*p =(AVLTreeNode*) q->getRight();
q->setRight(p->getLeft());
p->setLeft(q);
return p;
}


IAVLTreeNode* AVLTree::getRoot()
{
return root;
}


void AVLTree::remove(int key)
{
root = remove_fn(root, key);

};

IAVLTreeNode* AVLTree::remove_fn(IAVLTreeNode*p, int key)
{
if (p == NULL)
return p;
if (key < p->getKey())
p->setLeft(remove_fn(p->getLeft(), key));
else if (key>p->getKey())
p->setRight(remove_fn(p->getRight(), key));
else
{
if ((p->getLeft() == NULL) || (p->getRight() == NULL))
{
IAVLTreeNode* temp = p->getLeft() ? p->getLeft() : p->getRight();
if (temp == NULL)
{
temp = root;
root = NULL;
}
else
*root = *temp;
delete(temp);
}
else
{
IAVLTreeNode* q = minkey(p->getRight());
p->setKey(q->getKey());
p->setRight(remove_fn(p->getRight(), q->getKey()));
}
}
height(root);
root = balance(root);
}



IAVLTreeNode * AVLTree::minkey (IAVLTreeNode*h)
{
IAVLTreeNode* tmp;
while (tmp->getLeft() != NULL)
tmp = tmp->getLeft();
return tmp;  
}
```

Comment: 0 is a bukk pointer so "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" means you tried to dereference a null pointer.  There is no way to help you find it because the code you posted is not complete so it doesn't compile.  It would help if you could post the complete code so that we can compile it too.

Comment: You should be able to view a `callstack` or `backtrace` in your debugger, that shows you where you came - you should also be able to inspect the code and variables in your code. If for some reason that doesn't work, start adding `cout` lines in your code to show what it is doing...

Comment: Also, you should learn how to indent your code!

Comment: ok thankyou.I am trying to debug my code. It is throwing exception when I am trying to calculate the balance factor. Am I putting the height function and calculating balance factor at the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Your `bf` should be `left - right`